# Flutter- the method [] was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have been following a tutorial on how to build a social media app similar to Instagram, and although my code is the same as that in the tutorial, I am getting this error when trying to display a user's post:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#0c840): The method
> '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was: FutureBuilder
> file:///Users/Michael/Desktop/Flutter%20Projects/greenroom/lib/pages/PostScreenPage.dart:19:12
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: #0
> Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5) #1
> DocumentSnapshot.[]
> (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:29:42) #2 new
> Post.fromDocument (package:buddiesgram/widgets/PostWidget.dart:36:31)
> #3 PostScreenPage.build. (package:buddiesgram/pages/PostScreenPage.dart:26:26) #4
> _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:751:55)

This is the FutureBuilder:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: postsReference.document(userId).collection("usersPosts").document(postId).get(),
      builder: (context, dataSnapshot){
        if(!dataSnapshot.hasData){
          return circularProgress();
        }

        Post post = Post.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);
        return Center(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: header(context, strTitle: post.description),
            body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: post,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And this is the Post:

```
  factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot){
    return Post(
      postId: documentSnapshot["postId"],
      ownerId: documentSnapshot["ownerId"],
      //postId: documentSnapshot["timestamp"],
      likes: documentSnapshot["likes"],
      username: documentSnapshot["username"],
      description: documentSnapshot["description"],
      location: documentSnapshot["location"],
      url: documentSnapshot["url"],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the value isn't null

```dart
if(dataSnapshot.data == null || !dataSnapshot.hasData){
  return circularProgress();
}
```